# Exportar value de input Angular

Tags: angular, angular-6

Boa noite, pessoal.

Em Angular 6, tenho o seguinte código:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
selector: 'app-form',
templateUrl: './form.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss'],
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
formulario: FormGroup

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.formulario = this.formBuilder.group({
        pesquisa: [null],
    })
}
teste() {
    console.log(this.formulario.value.pesquisa)
}
}
```

Como posso exportar o "this.formulario" para que eu possa usa-lo em um service?

Estou capturando o dado digitado em um input atráves do ngSubmit e quero passa-lo para a url  de uma API (que está definida em um service).

Sou iniciante e não achei soluções claras o suficiente para minha compreensão.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.formulario = this.formBuilder.group({
        pesquisa: [''],
    })
}
salvarForm() {
    const formVal=this.formulario.value;
    console.log(formVal);
    this.meuServico.salvarPesquisa(formVal).subscribe(respostaDoServer =>{ 
           console.log(respostaDoServer);
     });    
}
```